# Secular alternative to "preaching to the choir"?

Tags: idioms, synonyms, idiom-requests

Is there a secular alternative to the phrase "preaching to the choir"?

Comment: An idiomatic alternative?

Comment: Can I coin one? `Lecturing the experts`

Comment: I know it only as _preaching to the converted_. I don't think there's an alternative and see no need for one.

Comment: @JamesWebster: It would be nice if you can find an existing one, but if not an original answer is also good.

Comment: I was going to suggest 'teaching grandmother to suck eggs' but, being aimed at advice rather than making an argument, it's not an exact substitute.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72711/are-preaching-to-the-choir-and-preaching-to-the-converted-synonymous

Comment: What @Barrie said. As you can see from [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preaching+to+the+choir%2Cpreaching+to+the+converted&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), *preaching to the **choir*** is a relatively recent Americanism (virtually unknown in Britain). Assuming secularism is in fact "on the rise" even in America, I'd say neither version has any particular religious connotations in the minds of most speakers - both expressions are just cliches.

Comment: Lots of suggestions in the answers... if you add context where you plan to use the idiom, it may result in more or better answers

Comment: @JamesWebster To me, "lecturing the experts" suggests that you're trying to teach people that know better than you, e.g. "Why are you lecturing the experts here?  Do you think you know better?"

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh The same can be inferred about `preaching to the choir`; "Why are you preaching to the choir here? Do you think they know any less about <religion> that you do?"

Comment: @JamesWebster, that's not really the same. "Lecturing" implies educating, whereas "preaching" implies convincing (in this phrase at least).

Comment: @BenLee I agree, but idioms rarely mean exactly what they say on the tin. Writing that I accidentally used a perfect example; there is no literal tin to speak of.

Comment: @JamesWebster No physical tin unless they are packaging experts.  At any rate, I think *lecturing the professors* is a bit snappier.  Many thanks.

Comment: Well, this phrase in the form "preachin' *at* the choir" occurs in a country song, which offers two alternatives: "tellin' old Noah all about the flood; tellin' a catfish 'bout the Mississippi mud". Graphic and beautiful pop poetry!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only one that I am aware of is *pushing at an open door*, which has been around since the 1920s and [was more popular than *preaching to the choir*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushing%20at%20an%20open%20door,%20preaching%20to%20the%20choir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) until the 1980s.

Comment: brilliant, I am going to start using that expression.

Comment: This diagram shows even more clearly the popularity line http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushing+at+an+open+door%2Cpreaching+to+the+choir&year_start=1910&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share= But preaching to the converted was more commonly used in the UK http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushing+at+an+open+door%2Cpreaching+to+the+converted&year_start=1910&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share= Nevertheless, ["push at an open door"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+at+an+open+door) has pretty much the same meaning as PTTC.

Comment: I like this phrase too--thanks. However, "pushing at an open door" seems similar to "beating a dead horse". Neither phrase has the connotation of telling an audience something they already believe. Granted, all (including "preaching...") are essentially cautioning against redundancy. Perhaps I'm over-thinking this.

Comment: … how do you close doors?

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for a similar idiom with no religious touch, I'd suggest [this phrase](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/gild-the-lily.html): **gild the lily**

> gild or paint the lily
>
> To attempt to beautify that which is already beautiful  (Chambers)

Another [similar phrase](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/carry-coals-to-newcastle.html) is **carry coals to Newcastle**.

> To take a thing where it is already most abundant

Comment: I don't think this is particularly close to the meaning of OP's cliche. Even [kicking at an open door](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kicking+at+an+open+door&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [teaching your grandmother to suck eggs](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grandmother+to+suck+eggs&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) seem closer to me, and they're not that good either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree  “gild or paint the lily” isn't relevant, but  “carry coals to Newcastle” is.  (But might have been added while you were writing comment.)

Comment: @jwpat7: You're right - "coals to Newcastle" wasn't there when I started my comment. But to be honest, I can't imagine anyone saying it with OP's intended meaning, whereas I'm pretty sure people do indeed use *pushing at an open door* with that exact sense sometimes.

Comment: `+2`: +1 for having an answer worthy of an upvote, and +1 because I'm from Newcastle =D

Comment: Neither carrying coals nor gilding lillies gets anywhere near where "preaching to the choir" goes.

Comment: Actually I know *preaching to the choir* as *singing to the choir*.

Comment: In German, the equivalent phrase would be "[carry owls to Athens](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulen_nach_Athen_tragen)". Interestingly, the Wikipedia article links to "coals to Newcastle" when clicking on the "English version" link for that page.

Comment: I love *carry coals to Newcastle*. Always cracks me up! ...Even though I'm not exactly sure it can be used in place of *preaching to the choir* 100% of the time.

Answer (score 7):

***"Beating a dead horse"*** has the same meaning as ***preaching to the choir***, minus the religious connotation, in that nothing is to be further accomplished by continuing.  For the skeptical - reason along with me . . .

> **When one "preaches to the choir", the choir is already converted and    therefore does not need to be further convinced (converted).**
>
> **When one beats a dead horse, no additional beating will make the horse any deader, so there is no need to continue beating it. (poor
>   beast)**

Comment: Except in many contexts I've seen and heard, "beating a dead horse" is used around a strong disagreement that's almost become an impasse, as in, "Let's move on, we're beating a dead horse." If you were preaching to the choir, there would be no need to beat the dead horse, because everyone would have agreed with you from the outset.

Comment: @Kristina It could be because the choir is converted, but we don't actually know that; what we do know is that the choir is there every mass or service hearing the same thing. In other words, they've heard it all before - they already know a thousand times over.

Comment: I do not find beating a dead horse in any way related to trying to convince people who are already convinced

Comment: @mplungjan, for what it's worth, the expression is figurative, of course, and a very common idiom here in the US.

Comment: But beating a dead horse is an expression of frustration when you try to convince someone or get someone to do something and it just doesn't happen. I have only EVER seen/heard _Preaching to the choir_ used by someone to tell someone else they need not go on with some complaint or try to convince them of something they completely agree on...

Frank to Joe: "I really think we should fix the bugs in our product". Joe to Frank: "You are preaching to the choir, man, I tried getting the boss to pay for that but it's like beating a dead horse"

Comment: [flogging a dead horse](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/flogging-a-dead-horse.html) and [preaching to the choir](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/preaching-to-the-choir.html) are similar in the sense it is pointless to pursue an action further but the difference is the direct object (people) of the two idioms. In the first, the people have a different opinion to the person making the proposal; in the second, the people share and already agree with the proposal being made.

Comment: Kristina, you say they have the same meaning, but then you give two different contexts and in each context only one is appropriate but not the other.  So how can they convey the same meaning?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh, it's the end result that is the same for both expressions and is what makes them interchangable: in both cases, there is no need to continue because there will be no further benefit to doing so.

Comment: We could continue this discussion, but that would be _b..._ Oh, wait, never mind. :^)

Answer (score 7):

Coining some of my own, because why not? Maybe they'll catch on.

- watering the ocean
- running up an escalator
- lending money to the bank

And one other idiom that means the same thing **and comes from the same etymology** but is secular is "on the same page" - which is what a choir and the preacher need to be if they want to get things done together.

Comment: Ha, after recent events in Europe, "lending money to the bank" is probably no longer correct.

Comment: Lending money to the bank is otherwise known as making a deposit to one's savings account.

Comment: On the same page is actually the better idiom. "No need to convince me, we are already on the same page"

Comment: I inferred that your escalator is running down as I run up, but they do go the other way. Indeed, `to escalate` is `to go up`.

Comment: But I do like `watering the ocean` as an alternative

Comment: *"running up an escalator"* eh? why would that be considered pointless?

Answer (score 5):

**persuading the persuaded** -  I thought I made it up but googling shows it was the title of a book review on sermons.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've mostly seen the phrase used to convey agreement with an opinion.
I think

> You had me at hello.

might be a suitable replacement.

Comment: Okay I kind of love this.

Answer (score 3):

All secular situations which involve non-rational belief can be regarded, at least metaphorically, as a religion. When people have chauvinistic beliefs about something being superior to something else, they are sometimes said to have "religious" beliefs.

"Preaching to the choir" **is in fact a phrase that used in secular situations**.   It is effective because religion is perhaps the best metaphor for deeply rooted beliefs which are not rationally based.

If you use the *"preaching to the converted"* variant of this phrase, then it loses some of the religious trappings, because the image of the choir (people singing in church) is absent. Chauvinistically promoting *anything* is a form of preaching, and conversion is not strictly religious. For instance, one can succumb to preaching, and thereby convert from Android to iPhone.

How about a political equivalent? Someone seeking political support can be said to be *wooing* the caucus.  If someone already has the unanimous support of those people, she is *"wooing her supporters"*.

Sales and marketing? *"pitching product to its users"*.

Civil liberties? *"Bringing a {sling shot|BB gun} to an NRA gathering*. (Those you are preaching to have already hold even more extreme versions of your view.)

What if the intended meaning **is** in fact "passing along rational information to people who already possess it" rather than preaching beliefs? "Look, what you're doing here is like *teaching fractions to engineers*. Tell us something we don't know".

Comment: "To preach to the converted" is older than "to preach to the choir" and actually makes more sense. A priest/vicar/reverend/pastor doesn't deliver a sermon to the group of singers but to his congregation. If anything "...to the converted" has greater religious meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the implication is that it's a _church_ choir, which are often among the most devoted members of a congregation. The details differ from _converted,_ but the connotation is the same.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I took exception to the claim that preaching to the converted has somehow fewer religious connotations; "it loses some of the religious trappings". Nothing of the sort. Those who attend church services are generally those who already believe in what is being preached. The choir sings hymns, and are mainly composed of young impressionable boys. Well... in the catholic tradition they are. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes, but if you _preach to the choir_, then they can [_sing your praises_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sing+praises) – in tune, even. ;^)

Answer (score 3):

A political equivalent to the religious expression *preaching to the choir* would be

***Energizing the base***:

> - *[Energizing the base](https://books.google.com/books?id=a5QnAQAAMAAJ&q=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&dq=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8HQLVZvKEMGhgwSZr4L4Dg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA)* carries a risk for Republicans. They could wind up alienating moderates and energizing the political opposition. [*National Journal*, 1998, Volume 30, Issues 18-27, page 1150.]
> - An even hotter ... phrase lighting up the brain circuits of the media
>     and blogaggle is *[energize the base](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/09/21/magazine/21wwln-safire-t.html?_r=1&)*. [*Hot's not Cool*, The New York Times Magazine, September 21, 2008, on page MM38.]
> - Previous Democratic presidential campaigns had used thematic trips    with creative modes of transportation to great effect in generating positive local and national press coverage and *[energizing the base](http://www.iop.harvard.edu/sites/default/files_new/research-policy-papers/king_morehouse_2004.pdf)*. [*Moving Voters in the 2000 Presidential Campaign*, David C. King & David Morehouse, Harvard University, Institute of Politics]
> - Rather than simply *[energizing the base](https://books.google.com/books?id=vpNDAQAAIAAJ&q=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&dq=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LXkLVanyMISkNp64hKAL&ved=0CC0Q6AEwBA)*, the DLC argues that    Democrats must appeal to moderates, the largest component of die electorate. [*National Journal*, 2002, Volume 34, page 3277]
> - His speeches easily rouse a friendly conservative audience, and    Bush's re-election in 2004 proved that *[energizing the base](https://books.google.com/books?id=_j4kAQAAIAAJ&q=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&dq=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M3oLVYPKKMK6ggT38oGQCg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ)* can 
>     be a winning strategy'. [*CQ Weekly*, Volume 63, Page 2841]
> - When political candidates get their supporters riled up and spreading    the word, we call it “*energizing the base*.” It's the
>     same with    companies and their customers. *[Energizing the base](https://books.google.com/books?id=FrB8QCQojyYC&pg=PT83&dq=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tnsLVYjSLPaAsQSYroCoCA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22energizing%20the%20base%22&f=false)*
>     is a powerful way    to use the ground swell to boost your business.
>     [*Groundswell, Expanded and Revised Edition: Winning in a World
>     Transformed by Social Technologies*, Charlene Li & Josh Bernoff,
>     Harvard Business Press, 2011]

Political and business leaders, like religious leaders, often speak and act for the purpose of inspiring their followers and customers to commit to a particular course of action. The *base*, like the choir, is inclined to respond favorably, but responds well to the leader's emphatic repetition.

Answer (score 2):

One related phrase that could be considered is ***surrounded by yes-men***, meaning that a person's close advisers and confidants are unlikely to object to a stated plan or offer any contrary opinions. It's often said of leaders, and it's sometimes considered a root cause of some bad decision-making or downfall.

This phrase can be found in several books; here are a couple examples, one from a social theory textbook:

> This leads to what is ordinarily characterized as sycophancy, or being yes-men. A phenomenon frequently observed in hierarchical organizations, an executive [surrounded by yes-men](http://books.google.com/books?id=a4Dl8tiX4b8C&pg=PA387&dq=%22surrounded%20by%20yes%20men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bR4yUvqCBbHh4AOlv4HYCQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22surrounded%20by%20yes%20men%22&f=false), is the natural result.

and one from a biography:

> The last thing LeMay wanted was to be [surrounded by yes-men](http://books.google.com/books?id=a4Dl8tiX4b8C&pg=PA387&dq=%22surrounded%20by%20yes%20men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bR4yUvqCBbHh4AOlv4HYCQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22surrounded%20by%20yes%20men%22&f=false), and he never once reprimanded anyone for speaking his mind during a debriefing.

Some authors have expanded the phrase to include both genders:

> A leader knows he is in trouble when he finds himself [surrounded by yes men and women](http://books.google.com/books?id=yLMwiBmLsosC&pg=PA168&dq=%22surrounded%20by%20yes%20men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aR8yUrn9NdOv4AOvg4HYAQ&ved=0CF8Q6AEwCDgo#v=onepage&q=%22surrounded%20by%20yes%20men%22&f=false) telling him how brilliant he is. If people think I'm brilliant, I've obviously chosen the wrong people!

Both phrases – ***surrounded by yes-men*** and ***preaching to the choir*** – can mean someone is quite unlikely to encounter any contrary opinions when proposing an agenda.

Answer (score 2):

As I’m not a native English speaker, I may be taking the meaning of ‘preaching to the choir” in incorrect way. But from the alternative proposition of “lecturing the experts” by James Webster placed immediate below your question, a cliché, “(Don’t try to) teach your grandmother to suck eggs” occurred to my mind from among very limited stock of my English vocabulary.

By the way, we have a cliché “釈迦に説法-Shakani seppo - preach to Buddha” as a counterpart to “preaching to the choir” (if it corresponds to “lecturing the experts”). It means a Buddha’s disciple tries to teach Buddha the dharma – truth of the universe, which is superfluous effort.

In Japan, we often starts a debate with saying like “This might be ‘Shakani seppo’ to you, but Japanese constitution prohibits entry to war under any circumstances in Chapter 9,” to a hawk.

Answer (score 1):

I made these up:

> To hold forth on yesterday's news.

> To propose the theory of evolution to a roomful of evolutionists.

Comment: Your second suggestion is perfect for the O.P.'s needs – and funny as hell.

Comment: Can be less tautological: "Proposing evolution to a biologist".

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same connotation, but somewhat similar [teach your grandmother to suck eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_grandmother_to_suck_eggs) and perhaps close enouh to what you are looking for.

Comment: Given the way the word suck changed over time, that phrase has the risk of having a sexual connotation.

Answer (score 1):

In the media in Australia a currently popular metaphor for this is `like being in an echo chamber`.

Answer (score 1):

An environment where much *preaching to the choir* takes place is a **nodding shop**.

> Our committee was once a nodding shop, but now members, like myself, truly lead our work.

Answer (score 1):

How about "punking to the mosh pit"?

Answer (score 1):

In the American south: "Don't take sand to the beach."  It relates from dating people to business.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider that this behavior is just plain

> **Harping**

[See the verb form](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Harping)

Generally, the only people that hear someone 'harping' on an issue are those within a community (choir/experts/converts) since they care about related topics and are not isolating themselves.

Thus 'harping' is inherently preaching to a choir.

Comment: [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=harp) shows that noun and verb *harp* is related to Old Saxon *harpa*, “instrument of torture”, which is entirely different from the etymology I'd imagined (ie like that of *[harpy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=harpy&searchmode=none)*, from Greek *Harpyia*,  “snatchers”)

Comment: Harping is not necessarily preaching to the choir.  Someone who harps is just going on and on about something and won't leave it alone - it does not necessary mean that the audience of the harp is already convinced.

Comment: Many in the 'choir' are agnostic in regard to issues that community / topic faces.  If you're staying around, it's *very often* because you are so involved.